# SAP NetWeaver Java EE AS

Tags: java-ee-6, java-ee-5, appserver, netweaver

Where is it possible to download a trial/community/developer version of SAP NetWeaver Java EE Application Server?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I would rather recommend this one over here: http://scn.sap.com/community/netweaver/blog/2012/07/12/netweaver-compositon-environment-73-trial-version-available-on-scn
It points to SAP NetWeaver CE 7.30 (Composition Environment). It's Java EE 5 compliant.

Answer (score 1):

Try googling - http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/sdn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/7005cdbf-ba8b-2a10-81b0-ebcfe8061f8f